# I can't see all texts written inside OutlineInputBorder in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
 Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 12),
                constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 50, height: 40),
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
                    ),
                    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
                    ),
                  ),
```

When I don't assign any borders to the TextFormField, my text goes forever. But when I add OutlineInputBorder, it doesn't show the texts.

[image]

If I enter another value, it does not show that value. becomes an empty TextFormField. However, when I delete it, I can see those values ​​are there. But it doesn't fit inside OutlineInputBorder.

[image]

As seen when OutlineInputBorder is removed, previously written texts are also seen and the line continues forever.

If there's something wrong with the width I've given in BoxConstraints, I need to fix it without breaking that value.

Comment: Did my edited answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 12),
  constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 50),
  child: TextFormField(
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
      ),
      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: In Flutter, BoxConstraints is defined as maxWidth.infinty by default. If I don't reduce the width value I get ExceptionError. As I said textFormField needs to have this width.

Comment: Try wrapping `Container` with `Padding`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, add content Padding in Input Decoration.

```
 Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 12),
    constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 50, height: 40),
    child: TextFormField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
        ),
        disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
        ),
      ),),),
```